# Android - TranslateAnimation related to image position

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I'm working on the translate animation and I got this problems.

```
imgLogo = new ImageButton(this);
imgLogo.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));
imgLogo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.twitter);
imgLogo.setX(0.0f);
imgLogo.setY(0.0f);
layout.addView(imgLogo);

final TranslateAnimation moveRight = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 410.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);

moveRight.setFillAfter(true);
moveRight.setFillEnabled(true);
moveRight.setDuration(1000);
```

The animation worked fine with this code, the image move along from (0,0)->(410,0).

However, when I changed the position of image x=0; y=800. Then run animation, the image just disappear at (0,800) and appear at (410,800), it's not moving anymore.

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Can you point what you want to achieve with this animation? Also I don't think using the pixel size of the screen the best way to generate your animation

Comment: I want the image move from left to right, or right to left at any point. At first, I have tried to use xml but it didn't work. In my code, the image is at (0, 0) and it moves along to (410, 0). If the position is (0, 800) then it should move along to (410, 800), right? But it just disappear at (0, 800) and appear at (410, 800). :(

Comment: Try my answer, if you think my answer is incomplete for you I can post a more complete code, but i think you will be able with just that line of code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RELATIVE_TO_PARENT when building an animation, just an example to slide something from the right to left or left to right:

```
Animation slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, right?+1.0f:-1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is the position of image. I have tried your code with position (0, 0).

Animation slide = new     TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, right?+1.0f:-1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);

It was moving. But with position (0, 800), it failed.

Comment: I have found the solution. It was related to x,y of the image. I have changed it to setMargin() instead of using setX and setY :)

Comment: don't forget to post your answer here to help others with the same question

Comment: I did find the solution. Instead of using setX(), setY(), I changed to setMargins(). And use the animation normally.
        marginParams2.setMargins(37, 898, 0, 0);
        btnFriend.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

Furthermore, If someone need to update the real position of object after translate-animation, then should use: ObjectAnimator.

    ObjectAnimator transAnimation= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btnFriendOF, "translationX", -192, 0);
                            transAnimation.setDuration(400);//set duration
                            transAnimation.start();